# Add line numbers to Rmarkdown text and have it restart on each page

Tags: latex, r-markdown, tex, line-numbers

I am knitting my markdown file and I have included the following in my header, which produces line numbers in my text. How can I make the numbering reset at the beginning of each new page?

header-includes:

- \usepackage{lineno}
- \linenumbers

Comment: You need the `pagewise` option of the `lineno` package. Can you make a [mre] so we can show you how this works in a document?

Comment: According to the documentation http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/lineno/ulineno.pdf, you can set the option [pagewise] (ex. \usepackage[pagewise]{lineno}, and then give the command \setpagewiselinenumbers

Comment: This worked great! Thank you al!!

Answer (score 2):

The `lineno` package has an option to restart the line number automatically for each page:

```
\usepackage[pagewise]{lineno}
```

Minimal working example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[pagewise]{lineno}
\linenumbers
\usepackage{lipsum}


\begin{document}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```